# Dependency problems - probably from flatpak

Tags: package-management, updates, kde, flatpak, discover-software-center

I installed a flatpak so I could use the new version of Kcalc on kubuntu 18.04. (It has calculation history now which rocks!)

(I know ... I'm going to upgrade kubuntu as soon as I can.)

Everything works fine except that I have an icon in my panel that says updates are available.

I ran Muon (apt front end) and did all the updates.

Then I ran

```
sudo flatpak update org.kde.kcalc
```

which did a few more. It also complained about me using an obsolete Breeze-Dark theme and I ran

```
flatpak override --user --filesystem=xdg-config/gtk-3.0:ro
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/flathub/org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Breeze#workarounds).

Now Muon and KDE Discover show no updates available, but the icon still won't go away.

When I run KDE Discover, I get a transitory error message about something being unavailable, but it goes away and won't let me copy it. It says something about kdenlive - which I don't use and uninstalled while trying to get rid of these messages.

It starts out saying 1 package needs updating, but when it gets done looking, there aren't any to update.

I don't know how to duplicate this from the CLI where messages don't go away.

How do I fix this so I know when real updates are available?

Comment: `I'm going to upgrade kubuntu as soon as I can` - You can wait till April, and fresh install Kubuntu 22.04, instead of now upgrading to 20.04 and then again upgrading to 22.04.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I know, but a fresh install takes me around two weeks to install and configure everything again and new kubuntu releases usually have issues.

Comment: FYI - To save time, you can first make a list of all packages you need to install, and them install them in one go.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks, but I've been at this a long time. I even have a script that reads a package list skipping anything that's already installed so apt doesn't change them from automatic to manually installed and another one that unlocks apt again if it breaks in the middle of an install.